# Format input values to hour and minute format (hh:mm)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one input field for time entry , need to enter hour and minute (HH:mm Format) .So how can input values automatically formatting . 
 
Eg: input values automatically formatting with HH:mm format (11:30).Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: with code and perseverance or a `type=time` `<input>` on chrum/opera/edge

Comment: What you need is the following plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/, hopefully you are using jquery with angular

Comment: There are some good angular timepickers around, do a web search

Comment: any directives available for formatting input numbers with HH:mm format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uib-timepicker directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker) for this purpose.It is easy to use and lot more customizable like you can switch between 12/24H etc. The doc explains it pretty clearly.

```
<div uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()"
  hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you just write{{"HH:mm"}} in $scope

value = {{a.value | date: "HH:mm"}}

Comment: is this an answer?